# Filtering list based on user preferences

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, custom-list, filter

On SharePoint I have 3 lists created.

The 1st list contains 2 columns: user's unique ID and user's name.

The 2nd list contains 2 columns: user's ID and a multiple choice of preferences of TYPES/CATEGORY of events they would like to hear about.For example: food events or educational events etc.

The 3rd list contains all the data on each event. For example: title of event,date,time,type of event,cost, etc.

What I am trying to achieve is to only display events that they are interested in when the user log logs in to the home page.

I am very new to SharePoint and looked through lots of tutorials.

Is it possible to achieve this function?

=======================================================

regarding comment below

yes. the new will enter interested categories in the first login

sorry i dont think i was very clear what i am trying to achieve

I am trying to create a web portal where a member of the organisation will log in and select interested type/categories of events for example: Bob(member) is only interested in seeing events that are about food and cooking, while Amy(user) is only interested in seeing political events

What i am trying to achieve is for that user to be able to select their preferences which is then stored and there will be also a list of events stored. i want to link those two fields and output the data in another page which should refresh as more events gets added and deleted

Comment: What do you mean by user interested? Do you ask user to enter interested categories in the first login?